# С помощью какой конструкции можно сделать поиск по всей БД?

Tags: php, mysql

Такой вопрос: как сделать поиск по всей БД? Не сложно сделать поиск по одной таблице... Вот никак не могу догнать, как же оптимизировать поиск по всем таблицам... Какая же функция или конструкция подойдет по поиску? Помогите, пожалуйста... Я тут смотрел статьи, но они ощутимый результат не дали...

Comment: как вариант. рекурсивно обходите необходимые вам таблицы

Comment: Уважаемый @tagir, бросьте Вы это дело. Посмотрите, как у людей это бывает. Ну, книжку (одну) какую-нибудь прочтите. Тогда и вопрос Ваш либо отпадет, либо переформулируется. Уважемому @klopp +1 за ответ.

Comment: я возьму ваш совет на первый план, спасибо!))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Иногда и правда надо так искать. Приведу пример: попалась вам БД чья-то. Вам надо в ней что-то поменять, а доброго PMA нет.
Вот и что делать?

Show Tables - все таблицы
Show Columns - все колонки таблицы

Дальше содержимое сравниваете с ключевым словом как строку.

PhpMyAdmin это умеет делать самостоятельно, если зайти в поиск в меню базы данных.

Comment: спасибо!
P.S. не знал, что в PhpMyAdmin можно сделать поиск, точнее с этим еще не сталкивался, а сейчас буду знать... очень полезный ответ!

Answer (score 4):

По всем так и искать: получить список таблиц (для mysql это show tables) и искать в каждой. А вообще, если возникают такие вопросы - скорее всего надо менять архитектуру.

Comment: но получу я эти таблицы, и в каждой таблице важная информация может быть записана по своему, в ячейке, и таких ячеек у каждой таблицы очень много... с выводом легко, но что выводить, надо же получить эти ячейки, смотря какая таблица... в этом и проблема... не буду же я указывать все условия if для всех таблиц, так как количество таблиц увеличиваться...

Comment: Вот поэтому я и говорю про архитектуру: значит, нужно организовать таблицы так, чтобы в них можно было удобно искать. Сама по себе постановка вопроса уровня "искать по всей базе", пардон, просто дурацкая. Очевидно, что у каждой таблицы должна быть своя структура, иначе зачем плодить таблицы, если они одинаковые? Другое дело связанные таблицы, например, когда нужна выборка из нескольких таблиц одновременно, но без конкретики тут говорить не о чем.